# Grails wont save in service

Tags: grails

I've a little problem with saving a changed object in grails. Here is my Code...

```
    Proxy p = Proxy.findByAvailableAtLessThan new Date()        
    Date newNextUseAfter = new Date()

    use(TimeCategory) {
        newNextUseAfter = newNextUseAfter+5.minutes
    }

    p.availableAt = newNextUseAfter
    if(!p.save(flush:true)){
        println p.errors.allErrors.toString()
    }
```

No errors are given, everything looks fine, but there are no changes in DB.

Comment: How does `Proxy` class look like? Have you debugged each line? Have you tried adding `println` to see whether the domain object is fetched or not?

Comment: Perhaps there is an underlying database issue that is causing the transaction to rollback because a services is transactional by default. Have you tried setting static transactional = false at the top of your service to see if it works without the transactional wrapping?

Comment: I think, you first validate the object to check is there any error?
If not then save(failOnError: true). It generates an exception and you can easily debug if there is any problem in persisting the object.

Comment: What does it print out - p.erros.allErrors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is a validation failure. So you should try

```
p.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

instead of

```
p.save(flush:true)
```

Comment: It wasn't a validation failure. The Database was locked by another process. But thanks!